# C++ Forward Declaration of struct ERROR

Tags: c++, struct, forward-declaration

I'm trying to do this in C++:

```
struct sagrup
{
    int imps;
    int clicks;
    int uclicks;
    int conversions;
    int * variable;
    unordered_map<int, struct sagrup> siguiente;
};

unordered_map<int, struct sagrup> agrupacion;
```

And I'm getting error: forward declaration of ‘struct sagrup’

I want to have that struct and add other struct into that ordered map so it will be like a tree.

Thanks to anyone that could help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple issues:

First, you do not need to use `struct` everywhere.  Second, are attempting to use an incomplete type with a template that requires a complete type definition (otherwise it doesn't know how to construct it).  That map should be declared as a pointer, not another instance of `sagrup`.

The resulting code looks like [this](http://ideone.com/Uib6FP):

```
struct sagrup
{
    int imps;
    int clicks;
    int uclicks;
    int conversions;
    int * variable;
    unordered_map<int, sagrup*> siguiente;
};

unordered_map<int, sagrup> agrupacion;
```

Comment: There's not necessarily a never-ending construction chain here -- `unordered_map<K, V>` doesn't have to have a member of type `V` in it.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield That verbiage was fixed.

Comment: The sentence "Second, you have a never ending construction chain with your siguiente member" is not necessarily true, depending on how `unordered_map` is implemented.  `std::shared_ptr<sagrup>` can be instantiated just fine, even though `sagrup` is an incomplete type.  There's no infinite construction chain in `struct X { shared_ptr<X> p; };` because a `shared_ptr` doesn't have a member of type `X`, it has a member of type `X*`, so the construction of a `shared_ptr<X>` doesn't need to construct an `X`.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Sorry, missed one of the sentences in my first edit.  Fixed.  Though, examples of `shared_ptr` do not apply to the OP's current problem.

Comment: Thank you!, using sagrup* fixed the problem. =) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Before the type has been fully defined, the compiler does not know anything about the type; i.e. what members are and their sizes and its in complete

Forward declaration is used only for references and pointers to such a struct.

Alternatively you can use:

`unordered_map<int,  sagrup*> siguiente;`

inside your `struct`

Comment: Forward declarations can also be used for template parameters, *only if the class allows it*.  For example, `std::shared_ptr<>` can be instantiated on an incomplete type, because the standard explicitly allows that.  But `std::unordered_map<>` cannot be.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` can use incomplete types because they don't really care about the type, but rather a pointer to the type.

Comment: @ZacHowland: Right, that's why whether or not a template can be instantiated on an incomplete type depends on the particulars of the class's implementation.  `shared_ptr<>` can be, `unordered_map<>` can't.